# single line command to create a file via Vim editor and save to a location

Tags: shell

I am writing a script for some specific test scenarios that requires saving the file via VIM with some text using a single command.

I tried the below command

```
echo -e 'This is some text.\n:wq\n' | vim -E -s /Volumes/DummyVolume/mytest.txt
```

This does create a file but does not add any content in it. Could anyone help in letting me know what could be modified to add content to this file as well.

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but consider `printf '%b\n' ...` as a more reliable/portable replacement to `echo -e ...`; this is recommended even by [the POSIX standard for `echo`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html) -- see in particular the APPLICATION USAGE section.

Comment: (But in the case where the only escape sequence you're inserting is newlines, you can just use `printf '%s\n' 'line 1' 'line 2' ...` and not need escape sequences in arguments other than the first at all).

Comment: (I'm curious, by the way, as to the details of the requirements that force use of vim; is this a test scenario where you have file-monitoring tools that need to trigger after the create-and-rename process that vi and similar editors use?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run `i`, the insert command, and terminate it with a line containing only a period.

```
printf '%s\n' i 'This is some text.' . wq | vim -E -s exim-test.txt
```

Note that it's just `wq`, not `:wq`.